# How to add a html element after last child of list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am able to add a content after last child of a list item.

```
li:last-child:after {
    content: "Content";
}
```

But how can I add an button or anchor after the last item,for example.

```
li:last-child:after {
    content: "<button id="listButtonAdd"></button>";
}
```

Comment: Use JS for that. CSS pseudo elements are not suited for that. You will have lots of issues when trying to add events to this element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need JS to do that, otherwise, you will be having trouble attaching actions to the created button. You can use this snippet as reference.

```js
$("li:last-child").append(" <button id='listButtonAdd'>Some Button</button>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: jquery doesn't count, why is this even an answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can't add tags to DOM with CSS, you should use Javascript/Jquery to insert tags to DOM, so you should use jquery append() method.

```js
$('ul li:last').append('<button id="listButtonAdd">This is a button</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will work

```js
var item = document.createElement("li");
item.innerHTML = "d";
document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0].append(item)
```

```html
<ul class= " list">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```